# Iterators in java for a traversable list

Tags: java

I have to implement a iterator for a Stack class.
My iterator class is called `Beg2EndGen`. It should create an iterator object that iterates over the elements of the traversable list in the order they appear, ignoring the cursor position.

```
public Iterator iterator () { return new Beg2EndGen(this); }
private Static class Beg2EndGen implements Iterator {
    ...
}
```

I am new to iterators. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  If you have no idea at all where to begin, I would suggest taking a look at the code for an existing iterator, such as `ArrayList`'s [`Itr`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr).

Comment: The best help you can get when implementing an interface is from your IDE. On intelliJ when you click `new Iterator<>() ...` you are automatically given all the methods you need to override and they just need to be modified. Also don't use the raw type `Iterator`!